# After APC, PgPool, Memcached, which server optimizations for Linux, Apache, PHP & PostGreSQL?

Tags: php, apache, apc

Which optimizations do you have in mind for a Linux, Apache, PHP & PostGreSQL server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good front end cache (e.g. Varnish) to keep as many requests as possible from even hitting the rest of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

mod_deflate for compressing data sent from server to client.